# Localhost:3000 takes longtime to get data from server on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, meteor

**NOTE**: Everything works well today, I don't know the problem but Everything works fine now.

---

I started learning Meteor yesterday on Window 7. Everything worked well through multiple lessons.

When I started today on Linux Mint.

```
meteor create simple-todos
cd simple-todos
meteor
[[[[[ ~/simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Then go to the browser localhost:3000, it takes long time loading without response.

When I tried this in the terminal, It displays the returned HTML in the terminal.

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

I've noticed that the returned output is without body content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/20ae2c8d51b2507244e598844414ecdec2615ce3.css">


<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.1.0.2%22%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%22comzm511li818nx5jr%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%229da5181b237af97fe169a3e1b0ddb7395c68caff%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%228e75859990afc3d8c7dcef4ef49fc89515f1f106%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"));</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?1a63019243b73298e2964e6d4680f25bca657726"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?71047b64b5196348bdbe5fd5eea9ac97a5a9eb14"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/logging.js?07e201b648f16be8435a4f666156995eeda0c750"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?da8974b7231dd8c0caccb5f322dcf97329d486d1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?fe7b46080c91ce482acf6fc326afbc5b176f0502"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?1f1dd2c35d300110fdaba51ce4473583bc3bf031"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?ac81167b8513b85b926c167bba423981b0c4cf9c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?9ea6eaae8d74693ce2505a858d9a5e60cf191298"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?bf8af2f26c8d96bf8b2e6b407d3ed69f23c2cd37"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?81b79d5cf96d00b4b7a28987debcffb665c17526"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/insecure.js?3dc9d4a2dad55999b5b15a447d57f3d5fb66b290"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?3cfe0c5981c197df33036a37574850f057e934a6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autoupdate.js?9a5ea03bf057815385bf569c7acc2c285c005491"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor-platform.js?499a2f8522e25820b1153c69a92751ccaae507b3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autopublish.js?c3059a78bb200b171099fc4fa1a9345101790ddb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?e1be090051b82f046484dccc2de7d747e50c7328"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?504589e1e9585dec8f9f6094e5a87b22de3783a1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-dict.js?1cb61826ceb23464171f17c2191c7e04a9b91508"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/session.js?daf192a7244079d45db32a6fc26ebc3881fc1aa3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?718526445deb4d9baacb6d92c551adea1d36c1e1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?dd8bac56f8fd3666d433d2285ae01e52597cc51a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/htmljs.js?567eb96d5d22631c03d6aca6afa4c42f0d1295f2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?20335b7b37165980ddd9f23943b2e5b00aae1cc2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ui.js?5a663333fd30f8fd913f110e0ef779e84f67c4b8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?376767bb0d2463b3b2615a1b90e77f6b22d39d7b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?495e58cf2465ba553324c68301cc62076b1fda1e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?ddfcd9be6cef3c8bb0263139937a05092e4a3fe9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/template.simple-todos.js?254c6b89dc5850fed9a9e89d00216fdc6b5eeb2e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/simple-todos.js?c2e184d448010d8345127ffbaf10ce04b6d355e3"></script>



<title>simple-todos</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

- I tried this on Firefox, SRWare Iron, and Google Chrome browsers in the normal and incognito mode.
- When I do editing in html file, the server said this and the page gets not response.

  => Client modified -- refreshing
- I did a new installation, and the same problem exists.
- I tried this `meteor --port 3030`, still the same
- I tried change from localhost to 127.0.0.1, http://127.0.0.1:3000
- I have a MongoDB 3 installed, I stop mongod, and the problem still exists.
- I tried this, and It display a blank page with title simple-todos

  lynx http://localhost:3000
- And when I cancel the server, the page is still loading.

Note: No errors appear in the output of the server

So what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I tried to install new browser called Maxthon, everything works fine right now with it.I also tried again with Chrome incognito mode, It works now.

But it still doesn't work with the normal mode of SRWare Iron, or firefox browser.
Do you think guys this will happened for users when publishing in production ?!
----

I want to mention another thing.
I have some extensions and plugins installed in Firefox and SRWare Iron browsers, **but** not in the Google Chrome
Those are AdBlock, Adblock for Youtube, Adblock Plus, and Adblock Pro.

I also tried to disable them, but still exist.

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser console ? (F12) Especially on Chrome.

Comment: No, no errors.
You know, hhhhh, I tried it today I works on both, Firefox, and SRWare Iron.
Hhhhh, I don't know what happened.

Comment: The reason you didn't see a body with curl is because it skipped running the JS.  The client code for Meteor is very JS-dependent.  If you can recreate the issue in Chrome, I'd suggest doing a trace/profile in the Dev Tools to see where the slowdown occurs.  I would venture a guess something fishy is occurring in the JS.